# C++ application compiles but does not open or hit first breakpoints after WinMain in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have an application that was working on one machine. I cloned it via GIT to another machine, with exactly the same setup as before.

Visual Studio 2017
10.0.19041.0 SDK version
141 Build Tools

The application builds without any errors, in debug and release,
but when debugging on launching the built exe, the application itself never loads.
It shows up in Task Manager, so it is running, but no window comes up

Furthermore, if I set a breakpoint on the first line after WinMain entry, it never triggers the breakpoint.

I have a couple of libraries in the application, which I compiled using the same version of SDK and build tools.

If there was a mismatch between libraries and build tools, I assume this would cause VS to throw an error, correct?

How can I go about debugging an application that does not fully start? What should be my first steps?

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE h_instance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE h_prev_instance, _In_ LPWSTR lp_cmd_line, _In_ int n_cmd_show) 
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);
    printf("Debugging Window:\n");

    std::shared_ptr<WindowsContainer> os_container = std::make_shared<WindowsContainer>();
    os_container->hInstance = h_instance;
    os_container->hPrevInstance = h_prev_instance;
    os_container->clientWidth = 3000;
    os_container->clientHeight = 1200;
    ProgramBuilder program_builder(os_container);
    
    if (!program_builder.Init()) return 0;
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: ***If there was a mismatch between libraries and build tools, I assume this would cause VS to throw an error, correct?*** Not always.

Comment: Step 1; make sure you try debugging with a *debug* (aka unoptimized) build.

Comment: Do you have any global variables? Perhaps there is some "static initialization order fiasco" This could also be caused by an AV like aVast which executes your executable in a sandbox the first time.